# tvOS topshelf not launching application

Tags: tvos

I've set up top shelf for a sample tvOS application, but clicking on an topshelf item doesn't launch the application. I've set up the display URL, though I'm not sure if I'm doing it right...any one know exactly how to do this?

Comment: Did you add an URL Scheme to your info.plist? Your display/play URL should match this. [Inter-app communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably miss the URL scheme in your .plist file.

**My info.plist URL scheme:**

[image: info.plist URL scheme]

**My displayURL of the top shelf item:**

```
var displayURL: NSURL {
    let components = NSURLComponents()
    components.scheme = "openApplication"
    components.path = "LiveStreamsViewController"
    components.queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "channelID", value: String(self.id))]

    return components.URL!
}
```

With this the application will open if the user clicked on an item in the top shelf. In appDelegate you can catch your URL and do something else with it:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    // When the user clicks a Top Shelf item, the application will be asked to open the associated URL.
    if let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("liveStream") as? LiveStreamsViewController {
        if let queryItemValue = NSURLComponents(URL: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)?.queryItems?.first?.value, let channelID = Int(queryItemValue) {
            viewController.pageIndex = channelID
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

In this example, I open another view controller instead of the main view controller.